# 'Constant Expression Required' Error while keeping formal argument as a constant

Tags: c++

This is a C++ programming code to display the values of array1 and array2 but I am getting a compile time error as 'Constant Expression Required'. Please Help

```
void display(const int const1 = 5)
{
    const int const2 = 5;
    int array1[const1];
    int array2[const2];

    for(int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = i;
        array2[i] = i * 10;

        std::cout << array1[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    display(5);
}
```

Comment: This is almost the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996258/array-initialization-use-const-variable-in-c

Comment: When posting question regarding build errors, always include the complete error output, in full and unedited. Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: However, note that C++ doesn't support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and that `const1` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: As well as all the above comments, consider using `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: How is it not a compile-time constant?  @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: Its a function parameter.  You can call that function with a run time value.

Comment: Constant arguments are only constant in the meaning that they can not be modified inside the functions. They are not compile-time constants that are set at the time of compilation. Having the compiler figuring out that you are actually calling the function with a compile-time constant like `5` is very hard, and not a requirement. All the compiler knows is that the function can be called with any value at any time during run-time, and that the value could just as easily come from a variable that is initialized at run-time.

Comment: But I have assigned that value as constant, it means it wouldn't change its value. @NathanOliver

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra Please read  Joachim Pileborg's comment

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks... It really helped me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, `const` is not always `constexpr`. Back in the days, `constexpr` didn't exist, so the only way of having a compile time constant was to either use `const` with a literal, or to use `enum`, because both of these are easy for the compiler to check the value.

However, in C++11, we added `constexpr`, which guaranties that a `constexpr` variable has a value available at compile-time, and state that `constexpr` function can be evaluated aat compile time if all arguments are `constexpr` too.

In your code, you can write your variable `const2` like this:

```
void display(const int const1=5)
{
    constexpr int const2 = 5;

    // ...
}
```

Now your code is much more expressive about what you are doing. instead of relying that the const may be available at compile time, you say "this variable has a value known at compile time, here's the value".

However, if you try to change `const1`, you'll get an error. Parameters, even with default value always as a value known at runtime. If the value is only known at runtime, you can't use it in template parameters or array size.

If you want your function to be able to `receive` the value `const1` as a constant expression from where you can receive it as a template parameter, since template parameters are always known at compile time.

```
template<int const1 = 5>
void display()
{
    constexpr int const2 = 5;

    int array1[const1];
    int array2[const2];
}
```

You will have to call your function like that:

```
// const1 is 5
display();

// const1 is 10
display<10>();
```

If you want to know more about templates, go check [Function templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), or this [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/)

Comment: Can `display<10>();` change the value of **const1**?, as it is a constant and may show an error.  @GuillaumeRacicot

Comment: Not really. You can see it as *inside the function display<10>, the value of `const1` is 10*. For integral values, template parameter are working in a similar matter than normal parameter, except that they need to be known at compile time. If you meant *"will the value of `const1` inside `display<10>` will be 10?"* then the amswer is yes, the value you sent is indeed 10.

Comment: You see, a template will not be a single function with a single `const1` inside. Each `display<1>()` `display<2>()` `display<3>()` are different function, because it's a template. The compiler will create, from your template, a bunch of different function, each with their `const1` inside, each with a different value.

Comment: I added link in the answer.