# Why do i get "invalid use of non-static data member" error when i try to create an array inside class?

Tags: c++

I created an array with the length of x but I get the error

> invalid use of non-static data member Test::x.

I tried to replace `int newArray[x];` with `int newArray = new int[x];` but still didn't work out.
When I declared the `newArray[x]` in the constructor or put `static const` before `int x = 10`, the code run successfully.
Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int x = 10;
    int newArray[x];
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
};
int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996258/array-initialization-use-const-variable-in-c

Comment: The size of arrays must be known at compile-time.  Use `vector` if that cannot happen.

Comment: Don't edit question in a way to invalidate answers please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int newArray[x];` won't work because size of a static array needs to be known at compile time. Adding `static constexpr` to the declaration of `x` makes it a compile time constant and that's why the code compiles.
`int newArray = new int[x];` won't work either, because operator [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) returns a pointer, which cannot be assigned to an integer. Having said that, consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @Downvoter Can anyone suggest improvements or corrections to this?